# How To Return only Child Model property in wep api response

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2

here Is my Models  ,here in my model PK is decorated  with Key becoz  in EF it must be . But as it is aslo available in base class. if I removed PK from Person it gives error as model has not assign a Key IN EF which is strange to me .

```
public class Person:TBase
{
    [Key]
    public long PK { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string ADDRESS { get; set; }

}

 public class TBase: Base
{
    public virtual long? FKTenant { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsDefault { get; set; }

}

 public class  Base
{
    [Key]
     public long PK { get; set; }
     public virtual string GlobalID { get; set; }

}
```

and Controller

```
[EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        try
        {
           IQueryable<Person> result;
            var  result = DbContext.Persons.Where(x => x.FKTenant == context.FKTenant).ToList(); 
            return Ok(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

i am getting response in postman is

```
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"bnVsbA==\"",
        "PK": 1001,
        "NAME": "VIVEK",
        "ADDRESS": "DELHI",
        "FKTenant":null,
        "IsDefault ":null,
        "GlobalID ":null

    }]
```

But my Intention  to get ouput response as below which should contain onlly name and address

```
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"bnVsbA==\"",
        "NAME": "VIVEK",
        "ADDRESS": "DELHI"
    }]
```

Any guide will  be appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ViewModel

write another class as ViewModel and when you want return object first map to new ViewModel then return it.